# EEG analysis free software?

Tags: eeg, data, software, analysis

I'm looking for free software for EEG data processing.
What free or opensource software packages are available for analyzing raw EEG data?

Comment: Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_neuroimaging_software

Answer (score 1):

The eegkit package for R is a good and open source toolkit for data analysis. It is easy to use and you can get really cool plots.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options that I found in [this](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_best_open_source_software_to_analyse_EEG_signals2) ResearchGate question.

The most prominent truly open source options seem to be [MNE](https://martinos.org/mne/stable/index.html) and [PyEEG](https://github.com/forrestbao/pyeeg) but I have no hands on experience with either.

Comment: Answers on StackExchange shouldn't rely on outside content; the idea is that these questions remain for a long period, perhaps indefinitely, whereas links break and outside content changes. You can still cite the source for where you're getting some of the information, but it's best to add it in your own words here, especially for something as simple as a list of software.

Comment: Right, I wanted to include the ResearchGate thread for reference, because there's more options mentioned in there.

Answer (score 0):

The main programs in the field are: Fieldtrip and EEGLAB.
These are MATLAB-based but can be run on Octave (opensource implementation of basic MATLAB) which would be a good suggestion if you ever have any intent on working with other people looking at EEG data in research institutions etc.

The only other real alternative is MNE (Python-based), as suggested above. I use both EEGLAB and MNE for different things and I think having the ability to use both is definitely beneficial. If you are more used to the Python way of doing things then this might be your best option, although it's not as beginner-friendly as something like EEGLAB (but might be more intuitive if you've never used MATLAB-style coding before).

Comment: Running those toolboxes on Octave may technically work, but I wouldn't suggest it especially for someone just starting out because they might get unexpected behavior. Octave is a pretty good clone of Matlab for basic functionality but they are not interchangeable. The python-based options are probably best if someone is trying to truly stay free of paid software.